# Will fluoride evaporate from tap water at the same rate as chlorine

Tags: water, kinetics, phase

Chlorine evaporation is an overnight process from standing tap water in a gallon pan. Does fluoride evaporate in the same way/rate?

Comment: There's crucial difference between fluorine and fluoride.

Comment: Were these downvotes before or after migration? Seems like a good question to me.

Comment: And this whole -ine vs. -ide thing is pedantic. Clearly, the asker means the vernacular usages. "Chlorine" and "fluoride" are added to drinking water. How do they compare when using evaporating techniques? I sure hope the downvotes are not because of this.

Comment: @fredsbend Chlorination of water is often by adding actual chlorine gas ($\ce{Cl2}$),  whereas fluorination of water can be actual sodium fluoride (NaF) which is a solid.  NaF has no chance of evaporating unless you heat it to over 1000 degrees C.   $\ce{Cl2}$ leaves the water easily like carbon dioxide coming out of soda.

Comment: @DavePhD Considering how the question was asked, I think that's exactly the information needed in an answer. The OP is clearly unaware of this. My complaint is if the downvotes are a result of the OP's apparent ignorance regarding what "added chlorine" and "added fluoride" mean chemically.

Comment: @fredsbend I upvoted.  It think some people here want to see more college-level chemistry questions maybe, I don't why they downvote really.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: no, fluoride does not evaporate in the same way/rate as chlorine.

Longer answer: chlorine will be present as covalent, molecular $\ce{Cl2}$. This is, when not in solution, a gas. Chlorine molecules leaving the surface of the water will (on average) not come back (at least unless there is a very high concentration of $\ce{Cl2}$ in the room's air, in which case you have other problems).

Fluoride, on the other hand, is present as $\ce{F-}$ ions (or other, complex ions) along with corresponding positively charged ions (usually $\ce{Na+}$, I believe). Even if the $\ce{NaF}$ were to be removed from solution, $\ce{NaF}$ is a non-volatile salt, and so would not evaporate away.

Comment: An imperfect answer because I slightly gloss over how ions and non-ionic molecules behave differently going into / coming out of solution. Suggestions and edits are very welcome!

Comment: Considering how the question was asked, I think you answered it perfectly. If the OP wants to know more about the differences between dissolved gases and dissolved salts, then he can look it up or ask a different question.